# query string problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have switched from asp.net mvc 1.0 to 2.0

My actionlinks:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Add bla", "addbla", new { id = Model.Id })%>
```

now produce urls like this:

`addbla/500`

rather than:

```
addbla/?Id=5008
```

does this have to do with the routing:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

How can I restore the old behaviour?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: Current solution insert: routes.
                MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
before the other maproute. still don't understand why the controller receives a null for id even for urls like this addbla/500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore the old behavior removing `id` from MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: that's what I did see my comment above. I still do not understand why a url bla/33 results in an id being null in my controller.

Comment: I didn´t see your comment, but my idea was to replace your MapRoute, instead of inserting it before.
Replacing MapRoute, bla/33 won´t work because there is no controller bla and action 33. It will work only with bla?Id=33
Inserting this MapRoute before the other one (more generic and with id) both url work in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lowercase `id` instead of mixed case.  I haven't seen this problem in the one project I've transitioned, but I consistently use the lowercase `id`.

Comment: I actually changed it to upper case Id from id. neither works. will update question